# php INSERT into column with variable name MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, variables, insert

Been looking around all over forums and found similarish issues like [MySQL INSERT INTO with PHP $variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893998/mysql-insert-into-with-php-variable) . But it's not quite getting to my question.

I want to use variables for the columns but I get errors with my MySQL insert statement

```
$columns = 'id, test';
$sql_store = "INSERT into test ('$columns') VALUES (NULL, 1)";
$sql = mysqli_query($db, $sql_store) or die(mysql_error());
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''id, Storlek') VALUES (NULL, 1)' at line 1

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem : Your `$columns` variable is string which is not true.

Try like this,

**PHP**

```
$columns_array = array('id','test');
$columns = implode(",",$columns_array);
$sql_store = "INSERT into test (".$columns.") VALUES (NULL, 1)";
$sql = mysqli_query($db, $sql_store) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Know that it says not to say thanks in the comments but this was exactly what I was looking for. The array in my oode was 160 fields and I was unable to get this in properly. This fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL command, after variable substitution, looks like

```
 INSERT into test ('id, Storlek') VALUES (NULL, 1)   /* wrong! */
```

It needs to say this ...

```
INSERT into test (id, Storlek) VALUES (NULL, 1)
```

or maybe this...

```
INSERT into test (`id`, `Storlek`) VALUES (NULL, 1)
```

So get rid of the quote marks surrounding your `$columns` variable.